Micro service audit logging. Accessing human readable text between services
My situation is that I have multiple micro services that each send audit messages when a change is made to their database. Each service’s data is separate for the other services, so cannot be accessed directly. The audit logging is achieved by hooking into the EF change tracker and capturing the changes just before a save. This works fine and the messages created are stored in a cosmos database. The problem I have is that we need to capture some human readable text when storing these audit messages. For example, service ‘A’ makes a save that contains a guid id. This id relates to a record held in the database that only service ‘B’ can access, so service ‘A’ doesn’t have direct access to the name that this id relates to. Service ‘A’ can make a call to service ‘B’ to request the record which it can then be use to extract the name and then use this in the audit log message. The problem here is that the initial save is now being held up by a service-to-service request that could fail or take a long time etc. I have simplified the scenario a bit as a record could have references to several other records so could need to make several requests to get all the human readable text. My system will hold a lot of data so caching the names locally wouldn’t be a solution. I have Googled but been unable to find anyone handling the above situation. This leads me to think that people don’t do this. Can anyone recommend a way to achieve the above or offer a better solution?

I don't have auditing on that level because not everything audit worthy is connected to a certain database model (that is usable by EF) or is connected to changed data at all. Like failed Logins that are consider Audit worthy (you system might be different). Said that getting human readable data is a problem for the Audit Log Reader not the Writer.

Reading between the lines, it seems you need to log a snapshot of some data of the record that the guid refers to? Is that correct? Are both dbs audit-logged that meticulously?

@Ralf This audit logging is just for changes to the database. Other things like logons etc are captured via app insights. My reason for capturing the text names as well as the ids at the save point is that in the future an entity could be deleted and I would no longer be able to get a linked name retrospectively.

@Fildor I have multiple databases and tens of services, so a lot of data spread about. I need to be able to tell a customer who did what if they need to know in the future. We need to be able to see if someone has accidently changed / deleted something or capture the details if someone had gone in and changed things for more devious reasons.

But if its no longer there what should the human readable name tell you? Ids are identifying human readable stuff typically not. One example, Ids are to identify users and and you have two users that exchanged there names. So at same point you might attribute the change in the auditlog to the wrong person because the historic information is a lie by now. Only having the ids will prevent those errors. At best by having historic data be able to resolve IDs by timestamp(current vs. back then)when viewing the auditlog. Its possible to reuse the auditlog for such a historic view if structured well.

@Ralf If 'Bob' unlocked door "Back Door", I would like an audit record to capture this. If in the future, the "Back Door" is deleted from the database, I will still have a record that tells me that Bob unlocked a door. If a user wants to search the audit records, they won't know the id's of these entities but they could do a search on "Bob" or "Back Door" and be able to retrieve some records. The audit log stores the database changes but also needs to be quarriable by a third party who has no exposure to id values.

I'm just telling you about the problems. Here if "Back Door" has become "Front Door" and vice versa the 3rd party will see presumably problematic data because the don't see that change easily and can't follow that change easily because they are not pointed at that change so don't even know to look for that. To follow those changes its best to do it by a search on the Id.

If its about exporting the log to 3rd party then it may be feasible to do the id resolution when exporting.

By any chance, do you have a datalake ? In order to achieve what you need, and without impacting performances, I would send the logs of the microservices into a datalake, along with the data needed to complete them. Then I would periodically run a job to join the logs with the data to get human readable logs.
Analytics from websites are oftenly processed this way, in order to reduce the size of the analytics. Only the id of the product is sent, then it is joined with the product table to have the detail of the product.
The only catch is if your data changes oftenly, then your logs will need to indicate which version of the data was used, and your datalake must have all the versions of each data, in order to join the logs with the right version of the data and produce consistent results.
